# Php Form Builder Class Hidden Fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I started working with PFBC yesterday and I cannot figure out how to pass my URL $_GET variables and I've read every document available to no avail. The other thing I don't see in the documentation are examples of hidden fields because I tried passing variables that way to no avail. I can see from var dump that the GET variables are picked up on page loading but I can't pick them up upon 'submit'. In my script below all variables show up fine except $ids. I've tried putting the GET variable into sessions, didnt work....hidden fields, didn't work, and the way its listed below,didn't work....for anyone familiar with this class its cake so some guidance here would help a ton. Im using pfbc2.2-php5 which doesnt have nearly the documentation of the old one. My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Step One: Physician Feedback</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MachForm/data/form_1/css/view.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body id="main_body" >
<img id="top" src="MachForm/images/top.png" alt="" />
<div id="form_container">
  <div id="form_container" style="background-color: #004F79; height:45px;"></div>
  <div style="padding:30px;">
    <div class="form_description">
      <h2>Step One: Physician Feedback</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("PFBC/Form.php");
if (isset($_POST["form"])) {
    if (Form::isValid($_POST["form"])) {
        /*The form's submitted data has been validated.  Your script can now proceed with any 
        further processing required.*/
        $ids       = $_GET["nums"];
        $name      = $_POST['name'];
        $title     = $_POST['title'];
        $dept      = $_POST['dept'];
        $phone     = $_POST['phone'];
        $tech      = $_POST['tech'];
        $latex     = $_POST['latex'];
        $eliminate = $_POST['eliminate'];
        $stock     = $_POST['stock'];
        $urgent    = $_POST['urgent'];
        $reason    = $_POST['reason'];
        $date      = $_POST['date+'];
        echo $ids;
        //header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    } else {
        /*Validation errors have been found.  We now need to redirect back to the 
        script where your form exists so the errors can be corrected and the form
        re-submitted.*/
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
    }
    exit();
}
?>
   <?php
$options  = array(
    "Order as needed",
    "Shelf Stock",
    "Consignment"
);
$options1 = array(
    "Urgent",
    "High",
    "Medium",
    "Low"
);
$options2 = array(
    "Lower Cost Item",
    "Needed for new procedure",
    "Reduces Length of Stay",
    "Improves Safety",
    "Reduces Procedure Time"
);
$form     = new Form("anything", 700);
$form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("form", "anything"));
$form->configure(array(
    "view" => new View_Grid(array(
        2,
        2,
        2,
        2,
        1,
        1,
        1
    ))
));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Name:", "name", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Title:", "title", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Department:", "dept", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Textbox("Phone:", "phone", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_YesNo("Is this new technology:", "tech", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_YesNo("Does this product contain latex:", "latex", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_YesNo("Is the current technology being eliminated:", "eliminate", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Radio("What is the stocking preference:", "stock", $options, array(
    "inline" => 1,
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Radio("How urgent is this request:", "urgent", $options1, array(
    "inline" => 1,
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Select("Primary Rationale For this request:", "reason", $options2, array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$form->addElement(new Element_Date("Date:", "date+"));
$form->addElement(new Element_Button);
$form->render();
//var_dump(get_defined_vars());
?>
 </div>
</div>
<img id="bottom" src="MachForm/images/bottom.png" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This class makes this extremely easy. Not sure why I was struggling so bad. Just add these lines and pick up the POST on the back side. Works great. I really like this class.

$hide = $_GET['nums'];
$form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("hidden", "$hide"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This class makes this extremely easy. Not sure why I was struggling so bad. Just add these lines and pick up the POST on the back side. Works great. I really like this class. $hide = $_GET['nums']; $form->addElement(new Element_Hidden("hidden", "$hide"));